# c++ elliptic coordinate mapping

Tags: c++, transformation

I would like to transform the coordinates of a window from cartesian to an elliptical coordinate system. The transformation is:

x= e*cosh(eta)*cos(phi)

y= e*sinh(eta)*sin(phi)

and inverse:

eta=Re(acosh(x/e+i*y/e))

phi=Im(acosh(x/e+i*y/e))

(see p.14 of http://itp.tugraz.at/~schnizer/AnalyticalMethods/AnMe6%267.pdf)

So far I implemented the following:

```
cv::Size2f _size(33,70);
float e = 0.0f;
float eta0 = 0.0f;
if(_size.height > _size.width)
{
    e = sqrt(_size.height*_size.height - _size.width*_size.width);
    std::complex<double> z0(0,_size.height/2/e);
    eta0 = std::acosh(z0).real();
} else
{
    e = sqrt(_size.width*_size.width - _size.height*_size.height);
    std::complex<double> z0(_size.width/2/e,0);
    eta0 = std::acosh(z0).real();
}

for(int dx = ceil(-_size.width/2); dx < floor(_size.width/2); dx++ )
{
    for(int dy = ceil(-_size.height/2); dy < floor(_size.height/2); dy++ )
    {
        float eta;
        float phi;
        if((dx == 0) && (dy == 0))
        {
            eta = 0.0f;
            phi = 0.0f;
        }else
        {
            std::complex<double> z(dx/e,dy/e);
            std::complex<double> k = std::acosh(z);
            eta = (k.real()) / eta0;
            phi = fmod(k.imag() + 2.0f*CV_PI, 2.0f*CV_PI);
        }
        int x = 200 + dx;
        int y = 200 + dy;
    }    
}
```

The problem is, that the elliptical coordinates don't scale. eta is always greater 1, but it should scale between 0 < eta < inf. Eta should be <1 for points inside the ellipse, specified by _size and >1 for points outside.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Maybe you should say some more about the problem you want to solve.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but check that your double (multiplication) and division produces a double i.e. the divide by constants is either /(double)2 or /2.0
hope that help